# Bitmap pixel values are different on Windows 7 than they are on XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bitmap

I have a Windows Forms application that I am upgrading to target a newer .Net Framework.  For one of my unit tests, a greyscale TIFF image is used to create a Bitmap.  The pixel data is extracted and then run through an algorithm to determine the center of a fiducial that is in the image.  On Windows XP, Visual Studio 2005, .Net Framework 2.0 the correct center is located and the test passes.  On Windows 7 64-Bit, Visual Studio 2013, .Net Framework 4.0 the test fails because the center that it finds is off by a small amount.

I have inspected the pixel data on one machine to the next by debugging and looking at the Byte array.  The pixel values on the XP machine are a little different than pixel values on the Windows 7 machine.  It's the same exact image and the same code on both machines.  One other thing is that this only occurs on greyscale images, all the color images pass and the ones I checked had the same pixel values.  Lastly, the images in question appear to be the exact same width and height according the bitmap properties I inspected when debugging.

Here are the first 10 pixel values from the Windows XP machine:

```
    [0] 94  byte
    [1] 92  byte
    [2] 92  byte
    [3] 91  byte
    [4] 92  byte
    [5] 94  byte
    [6] 93  byte
    [7] 92  byte
    [8] 90  byte
    [9] 91  byte
    [10]    91  byte
```

Here are the first 10 values from the Windows 7 machine:

```
    [0] 85  byte
    [1] 102 byte
    [2] 85  byte
    [3] 85  byte
    [4] 85  byte
    [5] 85  byte
    [6] 102 byte
    [7] 85  byte
    [8] 85  byte
    [9] 85  byte
    [10]    85  byte
```

Here is the test method:

```
 public void Test_CenteringBottomMiddle8BitMono()
    {
        int centerX, centerY;
        DoCenter(path + "BottomMiddle - 8 - Mono.tif", out centerX, out centerY, "npf02");
        CheckOffsets(centerX, centerY, 0, centerOffsetPixels);
    }
```

And the DoCenter Method:

```
 private void DoCenter(string filename, out int centerX, out int centerY, string fiducialType)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(filename);
            CenterCalibration center = new CenterCalibration();
            byte[] bytes = ImageProcessing.GetByteStream(bmp);

            int numChan = 1;
            if (bmp.PixelFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
            {
                numChan = 3;
            }
            center.GetCenterPoint(bytes, bmp.Width, bmp.Height, numChan, out centerX, out centerY, fiducialType);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} (Center Coords): {1},{2}", filename, centerX, centerY);
        }
        else
        {
            string msg = string.Format("File: {0} Does Not Exist.", filename);
            throw new FileNotFoundException(msg);
        }
    }
```

And the GetByteStream method:

```
 public static byte[] GetByteStream(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        DateTime startFunctionTimer = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime endFunctionTimer;
        DateTime startTimer, endTimer;

        startTimer = DateTime.Now;

        int numChan = 1;
        if (bmp.PixelFormat == System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        {
            numChan = 3;
        }

        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
        byte[] dst = new byte[bmp.Width * bmp.Height * numChan];
        byte[] src = new byte[bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height];

        startTimer = DateTime.Now;

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, src, 0, dst.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
        {
            Buffer.BlockCopy(src, (i * bmpData.Stride), dst, (i * bmp.Width * numChan), bmp.Width * numChan);
        }

        endTimer = DateTime.Now;

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

        TimeSpan functionInterval, timerInterval;
        timerInterval = endTimer - startTimer;
        endFunctionTimer = DateTime.Now;
        functionInterval = endFunctionTimer - startFunctionTimer;
        //            Console.WriteLine("GetByteStream() Total = {0}, CopyTimer = {1}", functionInterval.TotalMilliseconds, timerInterval.TotalMilliseconds);

        return dst;
    }
```

Things I have tried:

1. Targeting the original .Net Framework on the newer machine.
2. Turning on and off color correction when creating the Bitmap object.
3. Confirming the pixel format is the same on both machines. Format8BppIndexed

I am pretty sure it has to do with the pixel values being different rather than the algorithm that actually finds the fiducial, but I could be wrong.  I first would just like to know why the pixel values are showing up differently.

Thanks for any help/clues.

****UPDATE****
I have made some progress thanks to TaW's suggestions in the comments.  He asked if the TIF was compressed.

When I look at the TIF Information with IrfanViewer it showed that it is using LZW compression. I saved a copy of the Greyscale TIF in question and chose to not compress the image.  When I debugged the unit test with this image I was able to see the values that I was hoping for and the unit test passed.  It appears that the compression is affecting the pixel values and something is working a little differently in my new setup.

What's interesting is that this difference in pixel values does not appear to happen on the color images, even though they are compressed with LZW also.

Any further thoughts on the reason this might be different on the newer setup?

Comment: That sounds strange. Is the TIF compressed? Did you control/check the ColorContexts (color profile)?

Comment: Thanks TaW!  I have updated my question with findings.  I am still not sure about Color Contexts but the compression was a good suggestion.

Comment: Hm, now that's even stranger. TIF LZW is supposed to be lossless; I had only asked for completeness' sake. Color Profiles, OTOH, are a way to make the display machine-dependent.. (In terms of pixel values; and hopfully machine-independent in terms of appearence.) If you have a color profile installed on one machine it might be the reason; even though the color images are (seemingly) not affected.